# Invalid_b58check error while originating contract

Tags: deploy

I'm trying to originate a contract and get this error: "failed(permanent: proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.ill_typed_data), (permanent: proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.invalid_constant), (permanent: proto.016-PtMumbai.destination_repr.invalid_b58check)"
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using an invalid address. Are you trying to originate with an empty address or something that you intended to replace before origination?

Comment: Thanks for suggest. I was using a wrong address in a contract field.